# Using results of a script to run another script in the same loop in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
Folders='/home/usr/Desktop/SEV'
for i in `ls $Folders` ; do
    for j in `ls ${i}`; do
        ./create-vod-hls.sh
        ./watermark.sh "$i/$j" "$i/${j/.mp4/_w.mp4}" && ./gif_creator.sh "$i/$j" "$i/${j/_w.mp4/.gif}"
        done;
    done
```

I want the gif creator script to use the watermark script results. the water mark script creates a watermarked video while the gif creator script makes gifs. When i run this code the gif creator script overides the watermarked videos and creates gifs out of non watermarked videos. How do i change this script so that after the loop runs the watermark script it runs the gif creator script of the results of the watermark scripts.

Comment: The reason i used ls is because the script runs through directories ie the variable folders is a directory with multiple directories where the videos are contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the sequencing of commands.

The line

```
./watermark.sh "$i/$j" "$i/${j/.mp4/_w.mp4}" && ./gif_creator.sh "$i/$j" "$i/${j/_w.mp4/.gif}"
```

should be written as

```
./watermark.sh "$i/$j" "$i/${j/.mp4/_w.mp4}"
./gif_creator.sh "$i/$j" "$i/${j/_w.mp4/.gif}"
```

The form you used allows the shell to *start both parts near simultaneously*.  Also, there is no good reason for using the "**&&**" in your script.

The form I recommend ensures the first part completes, **before** the GIF generation is initiated.